# Remove YouTube related videos in this script

Tags: youtube

I have seen this script to auto-mute video's from youtube embedded on a site:

[How do I automatically play a Youtube video (IFrame API) muted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted)

The code is available on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9RjzU/3/

However I would like to know what to add to this code to prevent related videos appearing?

Thanks 
Azzam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Javascript API - disable related videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418028/youtube-javascript-api-disable-related-videos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, all that is needed is to add `'rel': 0` to the `PlayerVars` parameters, like so:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

    player = new YT.Player('player', {

        playerVars: { 
                      'autoplay': 1, 
                      'controls': 1,
                      'autohide': 1,
                      'wmode': 'opaque',
                      'rel': 0 
                    },

        videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',

        events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady }
    });
}
```

You might also be interested in the full list of parameters available for the YouTube `iframe` API, found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this is much appreciated

Comment: FYI, the best way to show that appreciation is by accepting the answer!  
=P

Comment: Oh, how do I do that?
Edit: got it :)