# How to prevent related videos from showing up when pausing an embedded YouTube video (YouTube API)

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have a youtube player integrated into my site, the problem is if I'm logged into my google account, every time I pause the video an inline menu appears showing recommended videos. Using `playerVars: {rel: 0}` only removed the recommended videos from the end, so that doesn't work for this problem. I could be mistaken, but I think this is a new feature of the Youtube API.

So, my question is, is there an option to removed those related videos without logging out of my google account

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418028/youtube-javascript-api-disable-related-videos

Comment: Like I said, using that code helps with the recommended videos that display after finishing the playback of the video. My problem is, that recommended videos pop up whenever I pause the video.

Comment: Using `playerVars: {rel: 0},` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Javascript API - disable related videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418028/youtube-javascript-api-disable-related-videos)