# How to remove related video from YouTube embedded Iframe code in html?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I am facing one issue, When I am using youtube embedded code with its given iframe then it is showing related video and I want to hide that related video bar from iframe?

So is there any way to hide that related videos?

See my below image and code :

```
<iframe 
id="ytplayer" 
type="text/html" 
width="720" 
height="405"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&fs=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3";
frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen>
```

[image]
Also, I have used below code as well. but it is still showing more video links.

```
<iframe 
id="ytplayer" 
type="text/html" 
width="720" 
height="405"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?rel=0";
frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Javascript API - disable related videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418028/youtube-javascript-api-disable-related-videos)

Comment: no it's not the same, related video's are in the end. More video's are when you pause the content

Answer (score 0):

You have to use '?' when adding parameters to the url. Update the src with following

```
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?rel=0"
```

Comment: Disabling related videos isn't possible anymore as the behaviour of "rel" has changed since September 25th 2018. Setting "rel=0" will load related videos from the same channel as that of the video. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel

Comment: any solution there

Answer (score 0):

you can hide it with css by using

```
.html5-endscreen{
display: none !important;
}
```