# Getting an Embedded YouTube Video to Auto Play and Loop

Tags: html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get a basic Youtube video to auto play and auto loop embedded on a page, but I'm having no luck.

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin: auto"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:1120px; height:630px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/GRonxog5mbw?rel=0&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showsearch=0&amp;version=3&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;fs=1">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/GRonxog5mbw?rel=0&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showsearch=0&amp;version=3&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;fs=1" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
</object></div>
```

Comment: Did you look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/youtube-iframe-embed-auto-play

Comment: It's not the autoplay I am having trouble with, it's the looping actually. Sorry, I should have clarified.

Comment: I'd like to see an option which doesn't stop the loop if we do not have the tab / window on the foreground focus.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

YouTubes HTML5 embed code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GRonxog5mbw?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=GRonxog5mbw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>​
```

You can read about it here: [Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20121016180134/http://brianwong.com/blog/2012-youtube-embed-code-autoplay-on-and-all-other-parameters/) View original content on the Internet Archive project.

Comment: but the video will reload every time
how can i prevent it like in www.kolor.com where the video continue plying even if you turned off the internet after first auto replay?

Comment: yes i have the same problem
is there anyway to have loop like that?(continues even in offline mode)

Comment: in 2020 this works but needs to rename parameter playlist to list, see @tarik's answer

Comment: `playlist` worked for me in 2023.

Answer (score 50):

Here is the full list of [YouTube embedded player parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Relevant info:

> **autoplay** (supported players: AS3, AS2, HTML5) Values: 0 or 1. Default
>   is 0. Sets whether or not the initial video will autoplay when the
>   player loads.
>
> **loop** (supported players: AS3, HTML5) Values: 0 or 1. Default is 0. In
>   the case of a single video player, a setting of 1 will cause the
>   player to play the initial video again and again. In the case of a
>   playlist player (or custom player), the player will play the entire
>   playlist and then start again at the first video.
>
> Note: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in
>   IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player.
>   Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used
>   in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video,
>   set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value
>   to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL:
>
> `http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID`

Use the URL above in your embed code (append other parameters too).

Comment: Thanks. adding the videoid to the playlist helped me loop the same video again and again.

Comment: @Vadimo the prameters are still present in the documentation... I don't see why it does not work "anymore"

Answer (score 10):

All of the answers didn't work for me, I checked the playlist URL and seen that playlist **parameter changed to list!** So it should be:

> &loop=1&list=PLvNxGp1V1dOwpDBl7L3AJIlkKYdNDKUEs

So here is the full code I use make a clean, looping, autoplay video:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="425" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MavEpJETfgI?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&list=PLvNxGp1V1dOwpDBl7L3AJIlkKYdNDKUEs&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: In your example, the the list parameter is not the same as the video ID. Is that right?

Comment: This WORKS IN 2021! Fantastic!

Answer (score 5):

Playlist hack didn't work for me either. Working workaround for September 2018 (bonus: set width and height by CSS for `#yt-wrap` instead of hard-coding it in JS):

```
<div id="yt-wrap">
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>
</div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      videoId: 'VIDEO_ID',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    player.mute(); // comment out if you don't want the auto played video muted
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(0);
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Had same experience, however what did the magic for me is not to change embed to v.

So the code will look like this...

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cTYuscQu-Og?Version=3&loop=1&playlist=cTYuscQu-Og" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: [Youtube Dev Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)

You can now use the youtube developer sample to build the embed tag for you.

Click `Share` > `Embed` > `Developer Sample`:

[image: click developer sample]

There, you can build out the tag (show player parameters has the good stuff):

[image: show player controls]