# How can I get a youtube video to autoplay and loop.

Tags: loops, youtube, autoplay

I realize that this question has been asked before here: [Getting an Embedded YouTube Video to Auto Play and Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041088/getting-an-embeded-you-tube-video-to-auto-play-and-loop) However none of the suggested methods have worked for me. My code is supposed to hide the control bar and cause the video to autoplay and loop.

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="425" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/c_70mlRY-    4c?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0";loop=1;autoplay=1 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Works perfectly when embedded into a drag and drop site (blog, wix) but when I try to use it on my own website, a play button comes up that asks the user to play the video. After that, it loops.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, constructive advice would be greatly appreciated :) I am aware that the same functionality exists in html5 but I haven't been able to get a video background to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but I hope this helps others. It was a syntax error. I was putting my autoplay and loop outside of the end quotation mark.  My code should have looked like this and it's working now:

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="425" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/c_70mlRY-4c?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Between your `showinfo` and `loop` query string variables, you have just a semi-colon: `showinfo=0;loop=1`. There should actually be a URL-encoded ampersand there: `showinfo=0&amp;loop=1`