# How to loop an embeded YouTube video?

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, embed

I am embedding a YouTube video without playback controls, or video title, but I want it to autoplay and loop.  Everything works except the loop.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class='embed-container'><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yo19ZhO7CAc?autoplay=1&loop=1&cc_load_policy=1rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an Embeded You Tube Video to Auto Play and Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041088/getting-an-embeded-you-tube-video-to-auto-play-and-loop)

Comment: The solution on that question didn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shoud add playlist=VIDEO_ID at your src

```
<div class='embed-container'>
  <iframe 
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yo19ZhO7CAc?autoplay=1&loop=1&cc_load_policy=1rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&playlist=Yo19ZhO7CAc" 
      frameborder="0" 
      allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: V E R Y  N I C E.  I T   W O R K E S