# Youtube embed video with autoplay and loop fire only twice

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, embed, autoplay

I used following code to embed YT video on my website together with `autoplay` and `loop`, everything is working smoothly, yet i found that it loop only once. So `autoplay` fire and then  video fire once more and that's it - next i see only infinity loader. Any idea why its so and how can i make this an infinity loop? I'm basing on information found on https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en

```
<iframe width="1000px" height="560px" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID/?playlist=VIDEOID&controls=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the IFrame Player API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop), it is stated here that:

> The loop parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame
>   embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. **Currently,
>   the `loop parameter` only works in the AS3 player when used in
>   conjunction with the playlist parameter**. To loop a single video, set
>   the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to
>   the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL.

If you want to know how the different parameters of Embedded player works, you can check this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) for it.

Also try to use this if it works on your case.

```
<iframe width="1000px" height="560px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID/?playlist=VIDEOID&controls=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041088/getting-an-embeded-you-tube-video-to-auto-play-and-loop).