# looping a video html in squarespace

Tags: html, video, squarespace

hi there I'm using this html code to auto play a video on my site. What would I have to add to it to continuously loop the video?

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an Embedded YouTube Video to Auto Play and Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041088/getting-an-embedded-youtube-video-to-auto-play-and-loop)

Comment: This worked for a while but now it's no longer looping. I'm not sure why.  If I could get another code that loops that would be great! I think maybe because even though the video didn't have sound, the volume on the youtube video was running so maybe squarespace stopped it after a while, I'm not sure. 

The other thing with this was that the youtube player was embedded but would prefer just a video looping. 

And it wasn't responsive so it got cut in half when viewing it on a mobile screen. 

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: You would need to ask another question, the comments are not for subsequent Q&A. Also - this is a duplicate so will likely be closed. I would suggest asking squarespace support if you believe their platform is doing something odd.