# Javascript. Echo the variable value later in the same script

Tags: javascript, echo

I have an array of youtube videoIDs. The script selects a random videoID. I need to echo this value in the same script. The script without that random variable works now with

```
videoId: 'NmhLuCSyBJg'
```

i need

```
alert(chosen_vid) 
videoId: 'document.write(chosen_vid)'
```

alert works, but, document.write does not suit here, need some kind of "echo"

the original script is [How do I automatically play a Youtube video (IFrame API) muted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted)

SOLVED! 
videoId: ' HERE I HAVE PUT THE WAY, I WAS GETTING THE VARIABLE VALUE'

Comment: `document.write` makes me cry. Where do you want the output? `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chosen_vid));` or `console.log(chosen_vid);` .. Also, why are you using labels?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to use a variable.

Comment: Yes, i want to use a variable in the same script. alert(chosen_vid) - works 
videoId: '(chosen_vid)' - i want it here

Comment: Then just use the variable.

Comment: SLaks, i can use the variable with alert. How do i change the line 185, that is wrong http://pastebin.com/t28rzclk

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you want... `document.getELementById('SOMEID').innerHTML = chosen_vid;`

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a function

Comment: the HTML is put together by another script, that needs my variable chosen_vid, see the original  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted . I just want to play random vid from my array muted...