# How to mute the parallax website homepage video sound automatically when I visit from other page (separate) to homepage again?

Tags: jquery, audio, video

How to mute the parallax website homepage video sound automatically when I visit from other page (separate) to homepage again?

When I click enter button and go to "our dna" page and from that page click on events link on menu. Now you will be there in "Our Events" at this time the video will be starting and user can hear the sound of video. User should not hear the sound at this point of time. We will have to mute the video sound.

Comment: You do have a backend right? Solution 1: add another parameter when you are "calling" your template from your controller. Solution 2: Use a cookie to track the user's browsing behavior like where the user has visited.

Comment: Please give the code clearly where i need to give. I dont have idea about js/jquery scripts.

Comment: Please check this below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted

Comment: If you don't know any js/jQuery scripts, you should find someone to do it for you. There are many ways to solve this, but to get exactly what you want, you need to ask someone for help. You are not really dealing with a simple copy & paste problem.

Comment: thats what im asking help in stackoverflow..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. (Voting to close).

Answer (score 0):

make an mouseover-event.

```
if you are over the video then       

    document._video.muted=false
    else
    document._video.muted=true
```

or:

```
$("#video").hover(function() {
     $(this).pause();
    }, function() {
     $(this).play();
});
```

Comment: Please give the code clearly where i need to give. I dont have idea about js/jquery scripts.

Comment: Please check this below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted

Comment: the code depence on your markup. do you have any html?

Comment: Its a dotnetnuke content management system website. its a html site only.