# How do you mute an embedded Youtube player?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm experimenting with the Youtube player but I can't get it to mute by default.

```
function onPlayerReady() {
    player.playVideo();
    // Mute?!
    player.mute();
    player.setVolume(0);
}
```

How do I mute it from the start?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/BFDKS/)**

---

**Update:**

[JavaScript Player API is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).
Use [iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) instead.

Comment: Hey Jonathan try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted

Comment: i changed code in fiddle its working check\

Comment: You have to use enablejsapi=1 in URL

Comment: mostly duped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Turns out `player.mute()` works fine. It only needed the parameter `enablejsapi=1`. Initial test in the fiddle didn't work because the player initiation had an error. The following works.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/zJ7hUvU-d2Q?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JS:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
    player.playVideo();
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/BFDKS/9/)**

<sup>Credit to Gagandeep Singh and Anton King for pointing to `enablejsapi=1`</sup>

Comment: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.youtube.com').

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. And your demo plays sound.

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't mute the video.

Comment: [Here's the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFDKS/966/) with a real youtube video and not the `youtube-nocookie` one used in here

Answer (score 11):

All above answers didn't work for me for some reason. It might be weird wordpress theme that I had to use or depreciated methods at Youtube API, I'm not sure. The only way of muting the player was to insert the code below into  tag.

```js
// Loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replaces the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'YOUR_VIDEO_ID',
        playerVars: {
          autoplay: 1,
          controls: 1,
          disablekb: 1,
          hl: 'ru-ru',
          loop: 1,
          modestbranding: 1,
          showinfo: 0,
          autohide: 1,
          color: 'white',
          iv_load_policy: 3,
          theme: 'light',
          rel: 0
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        }
    });
  }

function onPlayerReady(event){
    player.mute();
}
```

```html
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's important to note that YouTube API mandates you run this within your markup directly within a `<script>` tag, or via a standard `document.onLoad()` native listener and not as a named function.

Otherwise it will not natively bind the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` function to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
var youtubeplayer = iframe.getElementById('ytplayer');
youtubeplayer .setVolume(0);
```

And below is your fiddle updated version,

**NOTE: Must include enablejsapi=1 in video url**

```
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.playVideo();
        // Mute?!
        //player.mute(); instead of this use below
        event.target.mute();
        //player.setVolume(0);
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/antoKing/XQ5ua/)
Hope this helps...

Comment: Your demo is not muted when I play it.

Comment: enablejsapi=1 need to be used in url... i updated check @Jonathan

Comment: I think it seems to work since it remembers if you muted it by hand, I can't get it to work consistently.

Comment: What error you getting? anything in console? Have you debuged that?

Comment: `player.mute();` didn't work because `onPlayerStateChange` was undefined.

Comment: @Jonathan so everything working as the enablejsapi=1 right? My Demo too?

Comment: `onPlayerStateChange` is also undefined in your demo, that's why it doesn't work even with `enablejsapi=1`. But yes everything works now. Thanks!