# Mute Youtube video on Squarespace

Tags: loops, youtube-api, video-streaming

I want to add a iframe video on my squarespace page with mute and loop functions. I tried Youtube API but it did not work out. Please help!

Comment: What did you try? Code?

Comment: I tried Youtube API customised block but when i tried embedding it with squarespace, it was not visible. "This block contains embedded scripts. Embedded scripts are disabled while you're logged in and editing your site.
PREVIEW IN SAFE MODE
"

Comment: Sounds like the error gave you all the info you need. "Embedded scripts are disabled while you're logged in and editing your site."

Comment: I tried logging out and get in as a visitor. But the video was not popping up.

Comment: So when you logged out and got in as a visitor did it give you any errors? Could we see your code?

Comment: http://www.allsoftlearn.com/internet/how-to-embed-a-youtube-video-with-sound-muted/

I used this custom Youtube API.

Comment: That doesn't really help. What is the code that you have? And when you logged out and got in as a visitor did it give you any errors?

Comment: When i logged out and got in as a visitor, nothing was visible. Only when i was logged in, "This block contains embedded scripts. Embedded scripts are disabled while you're logged in and editing your site."  was popping up. Squarespace takes iframe blocks. I tried some youtube API parameters to mute the iframe but it did not work out.

Comment: Ok well we can't help you without seeing the code you wrote.

Comment: <iframe id="myVideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3Pu5rDJZbwI?modestbranding=1&loop=1&autoplay=1&?version=3&enablejsapi=1&cc_load_policy=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: This is the code which i want to mute. Do you know of any parameter which we can append?

Comment: Do you have a closing quote around your src url? And I would remove the semi colon after the src

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868226/how-do-you-mute-an-embedded-youtube-player

Comment: Tried but not working. Squarespace just takes iframes and not custom JS.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't any way to mute YouTube Audio without using Javascript. You have to use Javascript to mute YouTube Audio. There is no way to do it with just iFrames.

Comment: How to use JS block on squarespace is something i am struggling with. Can you help out?

Comment: @vinayakmishra You said it yourself "Squarespace just takes iframes and not custom JS."

Comment: I believe you should be able to just use the <script> tag tho to add custom JS to your HTML file.