# Unrecognized feature: 'autoplay' error with YouTube embedded player

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Is anyone else seeing this warning in the browser console when loading a YouTube iFrame embed player using the data 3 API?

```
Unrecognized feature: 'autoplay'.
```

The error occurs in a Google file: www-widgetapi.js:110 it appears to be a JavaScript error (this is from line 110):

```
c.setAttribute("allowfullscreen",1);c.setAttribute("allow","autoplay; encrypted-media");
```

I assume the autoplay part should simply be:

```
c.setAttribute("autoplay",0);
```

The file is here: https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflkvQ6Kw/www-widgetapi.js

The error is even occurring on their developer demo page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

How do people report these things to Google?

Comment: Upon checking [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo), the error is not occuring, can you verify which part or what action you have done to cause the error?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 which browser are you using. In Chrome, I still see the error in the console on this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Comment: I get the same error from that page(youtube player demo). Also tried loading up the iframe API locally, and get the same issue. Even when autoplay is not used/referenced anywhere in my code.

Comment: I suppose that the warning message comes from the command c.setAttribute("allow","autoplay; encrypted-media");
in the widgetapi.js. 
The semicolon after autoplay doesn't look correct.

Answer (score 11):

I wonder if this:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

> As you may have noticed, web browsers are moving towards stricter
>   autoplay policies in order to improve the user experience, minimize
>   incentives to install ad blockers, and reduce data consumption on
>   expensive and/or constrained networks. These changes are intended to
>   give greater control of playback to users and to benefit publishers
>   with legitimate use cases.
>
> Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:
>
> - Muted autoplay is always allowed.
> - Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
>   - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>   - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
>   - On mobile, the user has added the site to his or her home screen.
>   - Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Has anything to do with it. I came up with the same problem and the article mentions that the way autoplay will be working from January 2018 (now! ) will be ***changing***.

I have removed an autoplay in my code, and instead used a technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868226/how-do-you-mute-an-embedded-youtube-player)

like so:

```
player = new YT.Player( videoID , {
    videoId: youtubeID, // the ID of the video (mentioned above)
    playerVars: {
        // autoplay: 1, // start automatically
        controls: 0, // don't show the controls (we can't click them anyways)
        modestbranding: 1, // show smaller logo
        loop: 1, // loop when complete
        playlist: youtubeID // required for looping, matches the video ID
    },
    events : {
        'onReady' : onPlayerReady
    }
});

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
    player.playVideo();
}
```

I'm not sure if this constitutes an 'answer' so let me know if you not and I'll remove it.

Comment: I appreciate the comment even if it isn't an answer. I'm not using autoplay, so it's not a question of what I do in my code. Perhaps they broke the script when they made the change you've mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

I simply removed the `autoplay;` from the allow attribute on my iframe element, and included autoplay=1 in the URL get paramerters for the src:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Kjf0PdhFqMw?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&loop=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&mute=1&wmode=transparent"
```

Autoplay works and that error does not happen anymore.

Comment: I'm using the data API and I'm not using Autoplay--I'm not adding the iframe myself. It really looks like a Google bug