# Javascript quick way to mute youtube video iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I am looking for a way to mute the video unless the user unmutes it.

```
<iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ShPQqM50Vz0?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I tried using this script but nothing shows up at all

```
 <div id="player"></div>
<script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
          videoId: 'ShPQqM50Vz0',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady}
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
      }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I automatically play a Youtube video (IFrame API) muted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted)

Comment: It isn't really as I clearly copied the code from there but it's not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load API over https:

```
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/frzwg0bm/

Comment: how can you make it loop?

Comment: and if I want to replace youtube with vimeo, do i just change the youtube.com to vimeo.com and change the id for the video?

Comment: No then you must embed video with vimeo API https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding