# Video Code: Mute and Autoplay

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How do i mute a Youtube Video with in my iframe block without using JS? Is it a way which can be leveraged?
-I do not want to consume Youtube API. Is there any way that videos can be muted with just API parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible if you are only using the YouTube API parameter.

If you check the [supported parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) of the IFrame Player API, you will not see any parameter here that can mute the video.

So the only way to mute video is the `player.mute():Void`.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/BFDKS/9/) for the sample code.

For more information, check this related threads:

- [How do I automatically play a Youtube video (IFrame API) muted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted)
- [How to Embed a YouTube Video with Sound Muted](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-mute-youtube-video/29149/)

Answer (score 0):

use `&mute=1`
example : <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UNIQUE-VIDEO-ID?&autoplay=1 **&mute=1**&rel=0&controls=0"></iframe>