# How to autoplay YouTube video with sound enabled using YouTube IFrame Api

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

The title says it all:
*How to autoplay YouTube video with sound enabled using YouTube IFrame Api*

How can I do this with the YouTube IFrame Api?

Comment: It's a Browser policy to no longer allow autoplay without user interaction.

Comment: What if the sites already been interacted with? How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at whether this can be useful? <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted

Comment: Have you looked at whether this can be useful? <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869372/how-do-i-automatically-play-a-youtube-video-iframe-api-muted